# How the audience does not notice voice difference when "singing-voice" dubbing?

Tags: soundtrack, dubbing, musical

How the audience does not notice voice difference when professional singer, with totally different voice, performs musical number and then lip synchronized to the actual actor?

For example, Marnie Nixon was "singing-voice" of many popular actresses in musicals, but how people don't notice difference in voice?

Only logical explanation is that Marnie Nixon had superhuman ability to exactly copy other people's voices? Which I highly doubt...

Comment: They might notice but they won't care. They'd rather hear a nicely sung song instead of some off-key but "real" performance.

Comment: Most people's singing voices do not sound like their speaking voices....

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of "willing suspension of disbelief"?

Comment: IDK, this doesn't really persuade me. Still seems very fishy. There must be some better explanation.

Comment: Why did you use Marnie Nixon as an example instead of pretty much every animated Disney musical?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Because animated film could usually hire professional singer to voice all the lines, since they don't need to be as skillful with acting. Also Marnie Nixon was used in many Disney's animated musicals too.

Comment: I like how people on stack exchange use "opinion-based" framing to, basically, shut up questions that nobody can answer adequately.

Comment: I think it’s more about how there isn’t one reason why people don’t “notice”. I’m sure some notice and don’t care. And others notice sometimes and don’t notice other times. And also voices are cast so that singers sound like actors. And there are some reasons we may never know. And Disney animated movies very often have different singers versus actors.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I didn't find any reasonably good explanation for this phenomenon. So I'll have to answer myself. I think most realistic answer is that not every singer can dub "singing-voice". Some singers are especially good at simulating other people's voices.

After this sound editing team applies some pitch/bass and other sound parameters tweaks to further mask singer voice to be almost identical to actor's voice.

I don't work in Hollywood, so I can't be 100% correct, but I think this is most reasonable explanation. Only true Hollywood sound editor could tell us full truth, but they generally don't answer on sites like this.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a very good answer to your own question. You ask why someone with "with totally different voice" isn't noticed - and you answer it with some singers are "especially good at simulating other people's voices" or "sound editing".  So basically - you're saying the differences are small.

Comment: @iandotkelly well I wanted to know what tricks was used to trick people int NOT noticing this. Isn't this obvious from my question?

Comment: I think you should re-read the question.  It doesn't ask how do they disguise differences or anything like that ... it asks how does the audience "not notice"